# Global path for .eps files

Tags: graphics, paths

I use an .eps image file in my customized letterhead.  Is there a place in my (Windows XP) file structure that I can place the file so that all of my letters inherit the image?  I tried putting it in my `localtexmf` letterhead.sty folder, but that didn't work.

Comment: graphics are searched along the same path as tex input files, see for example the example images distributed with the `mwe` package, so any of your texmf trees under texmf/tex/latex/*/xxx.eps

Comment: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Did you update the filename database after moving the file in the localtemf?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Specifically, I placed it in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\@MyStyles\templates\letterhead` alongside `letterhead.sty`.  I then updated FNDB and ran ps2pdf.  It compiles with no errors, but reports `Could not find figure file impage.eps; continuing.`  Then (among other things), `ps2pdf> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`

Comment: If tex finds letterhead.sty I'd expect it to find the eps, but I don't know miktex. does `\includegraphics{example-image}` work to pull in an example from mew package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I installed the `mwe` package to my local repository: `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex` and ran `includegraphics{example-image}`.  I get the same result.  The document compiles with no errors, but reports `Could not find figure file example-image.eps; continuing.`, and the image does not appear in the resulting pdf.  So tex finds mwe.sty, but fails to find the contained image.  I'm stumped.